# Ajuste na escala de cores no R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Boa tarde,

Criei um gráfico de barras utilizando um indicador para preencher as cores das barras, onde o mais próximo de vermelho é ruim, e mais próximo de verde é bom. Acontece que ele ajustou de acordo com os dados, de modo que o número 29 ficou verde, quando é um valor muito ruim. Eu gostaria de ajustar manualmente o range que vai ajustar as cores. Como fazer?
Obrigado!

[image: Gráfico com a escala desajustada]

```
graf_pecas_tipo <- dados_expandido %>% 
    filter(hierarquia0 == "PEÇAS + ACESSORIOS") %>% 
      group_by(hierarquia3) %>% 
       summarise(Qtd_busc = n(),
                Qtd_vend = sum(ind_venda == "S"),
                Tx_Conv = round(Qtd_vend / Qtd_busc * 100,2),
                Clie_dt = n_distinct(cpf_cliente),
                Preco_Med_vend = round(mean(valor_unitario_sem_acrescimo[ind_venda == "S"]),2),

            Preco_Med_sem_vend = round(mean(valor_unitario_sem_acrescimo[ind_venda == "N"]),2),
            Desc_Med = round(mean(desconto, na.rm = T)),2) %>% 

  arrange(desc(Qtd_busc))%>% 
  top_n(30, Qtd_busc) %>% 
  mutate(desc_produto = reorder(hierarquia3, - Qtd_busc),
         Tx_Conv = as.integer(Tx_Conv))%>% #ordenando as barras do gráfico

  ggplot(aes(x = desc_produto, y = Qtd_busc)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Tx_Conv)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Tx_Conv, vjust = -0.5))+
  scale_fill_distiller(type = "div", palette = "RdYlGn", direction = 1) +
  labs(x = "Tipo de Peça",
       y = "Quantidade de Orçamentos",
       title = "Quantidade de buscas e Taxa de Conversão por Tipo de Peça",
       subtitle = NULL,
       fill = "Taxa de Conversão")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))


ggplotly(graf_pecas_tipo)
```

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(base)`? (Ou `df`, seja como for que se chame o dataframe.) Nota: na instrução `ggplot` o primeiro argumento é `data` e esse argumento está em falta no seu código.

Comment: Por favor, se o problema é no `ggplot`, edite a pergunta com o resultado do **último** `mutate` para um dataframe. Qualquer coisa como `mutate(...) -> pecas_acess`. E depois `ggplot(pecas_acess, aes(x = desc_produto, y = Qtd_busc)) +`. No fim o tal `dput(pecas_acess)`. Ou com o nome que preferir. Peço isto porque assim podemos nos concentrar no gráfico e não no processamento dos dados até os termos prontos para plotar.

Comment: Quanto é um valor bom? Como são seus dados? Qual a escala de bom/ruim? O que quer não é particularmente difícil de fazer no ggplot, mas não temos como responder adequadamente sem uma amostra dos seus dados e uma boa ideia do que espera como resultado final.

Comment: estou tentando extrair os dados mas não estou cocnseguindo.. o range ideal da escala tanto faz, o importante é saber como ajustá-lo manualmente..
podemos trabalhar na hipótese de um intevalo entre 0 e 50.

Answer (score 1):

Use `..count..` como parametro para o atributo fill da função `ggplot()`, como o exemplo abaixo:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(year,fill=..count..))
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36827261/10328310

Comment: mas o que eu preciso é o contrário na verdade. minha escala está ajustada de acordo com os dados, mas eu gostaria de setá-la manualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, criei um banco de dados que assemelha-se com o seu:

```
# Criando conjunto de dados
df <- data.frame(Var1 = 9,
   Var2 = 5,
   Var3 = 7,
   Var4 = 4,
   Var6 = 9,
   Var7 = 8)
long <- reshape2::melt(df)
long
  variable value
1     Var1     9
2     Var2     5
3     Var3     7
4     Var4     4
5     Var6     9
6     Var7     8
```

Uma das formas de encontrar uma paleta de cores, e fazer de forma automática é via o pacote `RColorBrewer`. Ao executar a função `display.brewer.all()` você irá observar diferentes paletas de cores que você pode utilizar. Outra opção, é utilizar o site deles [colorbrewer2](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=diverging&scheme=RdYlGn&n=11). Nesse caso, a paleta que serve no seu caso é a "RdYlGn":

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(long, x = variable, y = value) +
  geom_col(aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = 0:10, breaks = 0:10) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value, x = variable, y = value)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn", direction = 1)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se você utilizar `direction = -1`, as cores irão aparecer na ordem inversa. A limitação dessa paleta, é que exibe no máximo 11 diferentes cores.

Como alternativa, use `colorRampPalette` e coloque o número de cores que você quiser na função que tu criar, esse seria o modo "manual". Nesse caso, deixei conforme o número de linhas:

```
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "green"))
ggplot(long, x = variable, y = value) +
  geom_col(aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = 0:10, breaks = 0:10) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colfunc(nrow(long)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]